# Why does viewDidLayoutSubviews interfere with animations?

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller where the views are laid out manually (no xib). This is done in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. I want to animate one of the views, but the animation doesn't work (no observable motion of the view) because `viewDidLayoutSubviews` appears to be called immediately as the animation begins.

Relevant portions of code:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    logo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 360);
}

- (void)shrink
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{logo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180);}];
}
```

The `shrink` method is called when another timer fires, so it's not called straight away on view controller creation.

If I set up `logo.frame` elsewhere and remove that line from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, then the animation works correctly.

What is the explanation for this behaviour, and what is a recommended way to work around it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to call animation method in `viewDidApper` ? Instead of use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` try to use `viewDidLoad`

Comment: The overall size of the view (`self.view.bounds`) is not available at the time `viewDidLoad` is called (I actually need this to position the view where I really want it). And I don't want the animation to start straight away, so it's not appropriate to start it from `viewDidAppear`.